# How can I plot Japanese-format dates on the X axis in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**I need to display X-axis dates in Japanese in Matplotlib**. The proper format is handily provided by [Japanera](https://pypi.org/project/Japanera/), which shows how to convert any date into a proper Japanese format

To format dates in MPL I usually use the [dates api](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) and in particular `mdates` / [DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter), but the latter works with a "format string" logic such as `"%Y-%m-%d"`

I would imagine I could hack this problem by working at tick level: 1) extract each `tick` label from the X axis, 2) extract the date, 3) convert it to Japanese and 4) set the new `tick` label

**Is there any more compact solution within Matplotlib that does not sacrifice MPL's auto-placing the dates?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it would take the form of creating a new label and updating the x-axis as described in the question, using the MPL function to convert the date, calculate the year and month, and then output conversion to the Japanese calendar. The premise of this code is that you need to pre-install Japanese fonts.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from japanera import Japanera, EraDate

data = pd.DataFrame({'MAU':np.random.randint(5000, 8500,(10,))},
                     index=pd.date_range('2021/04/01', freq='d', periods=10))

plt.rcParams["font.family"] = 'IPAexGothic'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_fmt(x, pos):
#     global YY
    y = mdates.num2date(int(x)).year
    m = mdates.num2date(int(x)).month
    d = mdates.num2date(int(x)).day
    t = '{}'.format(EraDate(y, m, d).strftime('%-E%-O年%m月%d日'))
    return t

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(major_fmt)

ax.bar(data.index, data['MAU'])
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I checked it in Google Colab.

```
# Check the location of the font cache.
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_cachedir()

/root/.cache/matplotlib

# Delete the font cache file.
!rm /root/.cache/matplotlib/fontlist-v310.json

# Installing the Japanese calendar module and Japanese fonts
!pip install japanera
!apt-get -y install fonts-ipafont-gothic

# Check the fonts you have installed.
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
 
fonts = fm.findSystemFonts()
for f in fonts:
    font = fm.FontProperties(fname=f)
    print(f, font.get_name(), font.get_family())
```

Comment: Thanks vm r-beginners, confirmed (but no need to remove, that's informative)

Comment: And by the way, excellent solution by creating a new dates formatter, thanks!

Comment: If I had left it each time, I would have run out of space for me to use, so I added the necessary code:)